# Setting absolute path to asset files for Craft 3 multisite

Tags: assets, craft3, multi-site

Currently, I have 3 sites set up in Craft 3 beta. I'm trying to get all my sites to share one asset folder by using absolute path. However, I can't seem to set it up. The siteUrl is not parsing as I would expect. I would get "{siteUrl}/assets/people/image.png".

[image: Setup on Craft3's asset dashboard]
[image: Inside general.php]

Answer (score 2):

Found out the answer on how to get all my sites on Craft 3 to share one image folder. So you have to set your base url for all your site to your original site's base url.

[image: Set Base Url for all sites to the same url.]
Then in your code, you just put {{ siteUrl }} before your image url. Kind of confusing since siteUrl is actually the Base Url in the dashboard.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables as a concept don't exist anymore in Craft 3.  You can read about it along with the recommend replacements in the Craft 2 => 3 [upgrade guide](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/master/en/upgrade.md#environment-variables).

Comment: So I set up my siteUrl using an array but I'm not sure what 'siteHandle1' in the upgrade guide means. Could you please clarify that? I tried doing 'siteUrl' => ['web' => 'http://craft3.dev/',  'web-dore' => 'http://dore.dev/', 'web-exp' => 'http://exp.dev/', ],

Comment: The site handle will be whatever the `handle` field is set to in the Control Panel under Settings->Sites.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I've changed the handle as you have specified, but it is still not parsing the {siteUrl}.

Comment: You probably need to do something like `{siteUrl['web']}`, `{siteUrl['web-dore']}`, `{siteUrl['web-exp']}`, etc

Comment: @Ryan There is only one input field for the Base Url and I tried putting what you've suggested, but the siteUrl is still not parsing.